# Multiple contexts in a single function: reuse, and cancellation

Tags: go

There are a few tasks performed in a function that all use their own contexts.  The cancel functions are being explicitly called if the context does not time out.  Something like this:

```
ctx, cancel := contextWithTimeout(...)
defer cancel()

doSomethingA(ctx, ...)
// verify no errors from doSomethingA
cancel()

ctx, cancel = contextWithTimeout(...)
defer cancel()

doSomethingB(ctx, ...)
// verify no errors from doSomethingB
cancel()
```

The names (`ctx`, `cancel`) are being reused, and the `cancel()` function is being manually called every time instead of waiting for the defer.

Is this an appropriate way to handle multiple contexts?

Comment: It is. And you don't even need to manually run `cancel()` unless you have a valid reason to do so.

Comment: @zerkms Is cleaning up / destroying the obsolete context a valid reason? That's the reasoning behind calling cancel() instead of relying on the defer

Comment: "Is cleaning up / destroying the obsolete context a valid reason?" --- defer would do that. "instead of relying on the defer" --- is it unreliable?

Comment: @zerkms - defer is not unreliable.  These functions that use the contexts can take a long time (tens of minutes) to execute so having the contexts live that long seems unnecessary.  I'm not disagreeing with you at all though.

Comment: "contexts live that long seems unnecessary" --- what kind of resource do you want to save in this scenario? But anyway, if you need to `cancel()` explicitly - go for it, your code in the question is okay.

Comment: @zerkms By the way all these comments were helpful, just in case you wanted to turn them into an answer

Comment: It's still too subjective :-)

Answer (score 1):

A pattern you might find useful in this case is to wrap the blocks of your code into different closures. The main advantage of doing this is that you can use defer to call `cancel()` which might be preferable if there are a lot of branches where you would otherwise have to call `cancel()` explicitly.

Depending on your preference you can deal with any returned errors outside or inside the closure

```golang
func() {
  ctx, cancel := contextWithTimeout(...)
  defer cancel()

  err := doSomethingA(ctx, ...)
  if err != nil {
    // handle error.
  }
}()

err := func() error {
  ctx, cancel := contextWithTimeout(...)
  defer cancel()

  return doSomethingB(ctx, ...)
}()
// Handle error of doSomethingB here.
```

This pattern is also useful for resources which need to be closed to avoid leaks like http response bodies, files and network connections.